# Starting with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I took a project which I have to use spring boot on it and I know some basic things about Spring but not too much. My question is should I learn Spring completely before start learn Spring boot or should I just start with Spring boot ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Spring Boot uses a lot of the Spring Framework, so to understand Spring Boot, you do have to know at least the basics of the Spring Framework.

Comment: I am not sure whether I know enough information about Spring, so it is good to make a refreshment on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rnside mentioned, spring Boot helps us reducing the boilerplate code for any Spring based application. Some examples are:

- It includes the dependencies for various Spring modules like core, web, mvc, etc.
- We do not need the XML configuration for Spring when using Spring Boot.
- It also includes embedded servers to run the application.
- In order to configure anything in the application like DB, mail server, security credentials, etc. , we can do it just by writing it in the application properties file.

You can take a look at http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-spring-boot if you want to learn how to start working on a Spring Boot app and make a basic application. Meanwhile, if you have any queries for things related to Spring, you can refer to other related links for it:

- http://www.baeldung.com/spring-intro
- http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Some really good videos for this can be found here: https://javabrains.io/topics/spring

Hope that helps.

Comment: It helped and will help a lot. As I understand spring boot makes life easier. It is not seperate from Spring. Thank you for resources also, I was looking for a good resource to learn spring boot but first I need review Spring.

Comment: That's Great! Could you please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

with only Spring , you can do everything without Spring Boot, Spring Boot helps you get things done faster .

Actually , Spring boot it's a suite of pre configured set of frameworks and technologies to reduce hard configuration providing you the shortest way to have a java webApp .But it still based on Spring , so as mentioned  before , you need to know at least the basics of Spring .